# Boosting Poet’s Cloak? (Pathfinder 1e)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, bard

I’m trying to make my Skald a bit more versatile to assist the party and the Poet’s cloak caught my eye. Not all the party greatly benefits from my inspired rages all the time but being able to shift it over to an inspire courage on the fly is always helpful.

*Poet’s Cloak*

> Even after cleaning and mending, this traveler’s cloak appears worn and weathered. For wearers with the bardic performance class feature, it grants the use of raging song as a 4th-level skald by spending rounds of bardic performance. For wearers with the raging song class feature, it grants the use of inspire courage and inspire competence as a 4th-level bard by spending rounds of raging song.

The limit of 4th level effect is a bit restrictive, though.

Would combining it with a few other magic items be able to boost the effect?

The main contender I was looking at is Three Reasons to Live.

*Three Reasons to Live*

> The horns of three disparate creatures (chimera, dire ram, and satyr) make up this magical instrument, interlocking into one shofar about 2 feet long. Once per day the horn can be blown to affect all allies within 30 feet that can hear it. Affected creatures gain sonic resistance 10 and a +2 bonus on saves against spells and effects that deal sonic damage, are language-dependent, or must be heard to be effective. This protection lasts for 10 minutes. **If a bard uses the horn to start a bardic performance, all effects of that performance are calculated as if the bard were 6 levels higher.** This doesn’t grant the bard access to new bardic performances; it only enhances those to which the bard already has access.

This would be the primary thing I’m looking at picking up, curious if this would effectively make the inspire courage a level 10 effect or if the cloak caps at 4.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I think that this question is answerable, but folks might be reluctant to also provide a list of every *Pathfinder* effect that can increase the effectiveness of bardic performances. Perhaps edit this question to omit that and pose it separately as a new question? (Even if there aren't many game elements that increase bardic music effectiveness, confirming that there aren't is pretty big O-and-by-the-way ask anyway.)